# Does LLDP support traversing through multiple switches?

Tags: switch, router, lldp

I would like to query a LLDP enabled switch / router for information about current FW, Manufacturer, etc... But I am not directly connected to the switch, but through an Access Layer Switch  or a Wireless AP.

Would I be able to get this information using LLDP, even though there are multiple physical layer hops.

Information I am looking for:

```
Inventory - Hardware Revision TLV (OUI = 00-12-BB, Subtype = 5) 
Inventory - Firmware Revision TLV (OUI = 00-12-BB, Subtype = 6) 
Inventory - Software Revision TLV (OUI = 00-12-BB, Subtype = 7) 
Inventory - Serial Number TLV (OUI = 00-12-BB, Subtype = 8) 
Inventory - Manufacturer Name TLV (OUI = 00-12-BB, Subtype = 9) 
Inventory - Model Name TLV (OUI = 00-12-BB, Subtype = 10) 
Inventory - Asset ID TLV (OUI = 00-12-BB, Subtype = 11)
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. LLDP is a link protocol. Like the other link protocols, it only exists on the link, and it will not be forwarded to another link.

Specifically, LLDP is to tell you that information for other devices on the link. That fails if the information is forwarded to a different link.

Answer (score -1):

Media Endpoint Discovery that is an enhancement of LLDP, known as LLDP-MED, may help you doing that.